# How to write a build script

Tags: build

I want to write a build script which can compile the code, run the unit tests and produce a nuget package.

Can anyone please help or point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Which language do you use? For C# you can use Visual Studio for instance and build it using msbuild for instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you mentioned nuget, I presume you use C#. I had the best experience with Cake for build scripts.

[Cake - Home](http://cakebuild.net/)

But seriously, any build system would do, goole is your friend for this. I would also advise against using powershell for this sort of job.